# How to extract the number sequence/characters after a term excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract the exact sequence after a term in a text and just returns the number.

I need the whole sequence to return, with numbers and characters between the number.

For example:

[image]

I'm using this vba code:

```
Function ExtraiSeq(rng As Range)
    Dim i As Integer, str As String, CharPos As Long
    str = rng.Value
    CharPos = InStr(1, str, "SEQ", vbTextCompare) + 2
    If CharPos > 2 Then
        For i = CharPos To Len(rng)
            Select Case Asc(Mid(rng.Value, i, 1))
            Case 48 To 57
                ExtraiSeq = Trim(ExtraiSeq & Mid(rng.Value, i, 1))
            End Select
        Next i
    Else: ExtraiSeq = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: sorry, I expressed myself wrong, I want the result to come with the characters, 
like this 3554/2013.62, 930/2014-62.

Comment: are there always two digits after the `.`?  for that matter is there always a `.`?

Comment: Actually change that,  are `/` and `.` the only other character beside numbers to be in the string?

Comment: change the `48` to `46`

Comment: it will always be a sequence with three or four numbers before the "/" then four numbers and then I will have a "." or "-" and one more, two or three numbers

Comment: You now have three answers that will work but changing the `48` to `45` will also do it with your existing, but look at the versions below.  You will need to change `46` to `45` in @jeeped's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try,

```
Option Explicit

Function justDigits(str As String)
    Dim i As Long

    i = InStr(1, str, "seq ", vbTextCompare)

    If CBool(i) Then
        For i = i + 4 To Len(str)
            Select Case Asc(Mid(str, i, 1))
                Case 46 To 57
                    justDigits = justDigits & Mid(str, i, 1)
                Case else
                    Exit For
            End Select
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I went by the results shown in the image (discarding / and . but exiting on ) or a space). However, the above should be easily adaptable to include slashes and periods.

Comment: Yeah, that would include . and /.

Comment: Thanks for the pickup; I hadn't looked through the comments.

Comment: New comment that adds the possibility of `-` which is `45`  Just an fyi.

Comment: If the op ever actually figures out what he/she wants then they could edit my response to suit whatever conditions they are thinking about at that particular moment.

Comment: I changed to 46 and it worked ... that's what I was wanting.

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer:

Preserving all the characters between the first number found after "seq" and the last number found you can use:

```
Function getNumbersFromString(strIn As String, strTerm As String) As String
    Step1 = Trim(Mid(strIn, InStr(1, strIn, strTerm) + 3, Len(strIn)))

    For startIndex = 1 To Len(Step1)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(Step1, startIndex, 1)) Then Exit For
    Next
    For endIndex = Len(Step1) To 1 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Mid(Step1, endIndex, 1)) Then Exit For
    Next

    getNumbersFromString = Mid(Step1, startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 1)

End Function
```

---

Original wrong answer:

I think something like the following would do the trick for you:

```
Function getNumbersFromString(strIn As String) As String
    For Each char In Split(StrConv(strIn, 64), vbNullChar)
        If IsNumeric(char) Then getNumbersFromString = getNumbersFromString & char
    Next char
End Function
```

That splits the incoming string into an array where each element is a character. Then it just tests it to see if it's numeric. If it is, it appends to the output.

You can use it as a UDF so in your cell you can just put:

```
=getNumbersFromString(A1)
```

If you only want numbers after your `"seq"` term you can do something like:

```
Function getNumbersFromStringAfterTerm(strIn As String, strTerm As String) As String
    For Each char In Split(StrConv(Mid(strIn, InStr(1, strIn, strTerm), Len(strIn)), 64), vbNullChar)
        If IsNumeric(char) Then getNumbersFromStringAfterTerm = getNumbersFromStringAfterTerm & char
    Next char
End Function
```

Which would then be usable like:

```
=getNumbersFromStringAfterTerm(A1, "seq")
```

Comment: You may be right... I'm befuddled by the example given as it outputs all of the numbers present in the first column. I'm suspecting either the problem statement is incorrect or the desired results are not desired results. If it's just everything after `seq` then this is a pretty easy thing to solve for without VBA. I'm hoping I'm close here with my assumptions as it was fun to solve from a minimalist/over-refactored POV.

Comment: Oh yes. I see OP's comment now. Characters after are important. Darn it all my hard work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Column "A" has your values paste this code in the VBA editor.
Results will be copied to Column "B". Run the Sub "CreateString" then.

```
Function FindReplace(CellValue$)
    Dim strPattern$: strPattern = "[^0-9.\/-]+"    'Pattern to only take care of numbers, (/), (-) and (.).
    Dim strReplace$: strReplace = ""    'Replace everything else with blank
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With
    FindReplace = regex.Replace(CellValue, strReplace) 'RegEx Function replaces the pattern with blank
End Function

Sub CreateString()
    Dim LastRow%: LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim strConcatenate$, i%, j%
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        ws.Cells(i, 2) = FindReplace(ws.Cells(i, 1))
        strConcatenate = ""
    Next i
End Sub

Function LastColumn(row%) As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    LastColumn = ws.Cells(row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function
```

## edit - result:

[image]

Comment: as per the comments above one would need to also include `-`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Function ExtraiSeq(rng As Range)
    Dim vS, vS2
    Dim s As String

    vS = Split(rng, "seq")
    s = vS(UBound(vS))
    If InStr(s, ")") Then
        vS2 = Split(s, ")")
        s = vS2(0)
    End If
    s = Trim(s)
    ExtraiSeq = s

End Function
```